# Domain names added in windows hosts file is not accessible from android emulator/device

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-webview, android-browser

I am testing facebook app from android mobile/emulator. For this I added a domain like,

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.web
```

in the \etc\hosts file.

But when i enter this url, http://mysite.web:8080/fb_post_log.html in the webview, it is not loading and DDMS log says that,

"Reason : The URL could not be found."

How to access local domains from android webview or browser without using IP address. I cannot give IP address in facebook domain name fields.

Thanks in advance,
JRH

Comment: Did you install a webserver? What/where is \etc\hosts file on a windows machine? How could that influence your android app?

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to happen when you enter the url in the webview? Is the webview part of the facebook app?

Comment: @greenapps, I installed tomcat and one html page is up for the use. As it is running in localhost, am giving a dummy domain name by editing, C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file in windows. So the url becomes "http://mysite.web:8080/fb_post_log.html". But when I enter the same in mobile (my laptop and mobile using the same network), it says URL could not found. I am expecting that ,a facebook post should happen on clicking the button provided in the html page. And this is working fine in my desktop web.

Comment: If you use the webview on your phone in the same network then there is no reason that hosts files on other pc/devices have influence. You could as well try from another pc in your network. Every device only will use its local hosts file. You have to use the host name of your pc in the webview.

Comment: The request from your phone goes directly though your router to the internet. It will completely bypass your pc. When you use your pc host name (or ip) it goes to the router first but than the router delivers it to the pc.

Comment: You did not explain why using an ip address in an url for your html page has someting to do with restrictions for input fields.

Comment: @greenapps, I made html page for posting content to facebook. Facebook is expecting a valid domain name for the appdomain field. For that, I created the dummy domain name in the \etc\hosts file and used it. is this clear for for you? please reply if I need to add more.

Comment: No not at all. Do you realise that i don't know the input fields in that html form!? That i do not know why facebook would wanted to know an appdomain which is only on your computer and unreachable for facebook. And further you should start with answering my remark/question: `You did not explain why using an ip address in an url for your html page has someting to do with restrictions for input fields.`.